# Passing TextView in new Intent with ArrayList

Tags: arraylist, android-intent, android-recyclerview, android-arrayadapter, settext

I have created an app which has an click listener to open up a new activity. In that new activity, it has a template which descriptions I would like to change according to the ArrayList values I code. However, I can't seem to change it. All it shows is an empty text view.

Here is my MainActivity,

```
    package android.com.example.weddingappfinale;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import Adapters.MuaAdapter;
import CustomerActivities.Customer1Activity;

public class MuaActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private MuaAdapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mua_list);

        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Make Up Artists");
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        final ArrayList<MuaView> muaView = new ArrayList<>();
        muaView.add(new MuaView(R.drawable.mua_image, "Shima Matin Bridal Services", "Shima Matin started in 2012"));

        // ArrayList

        mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_list);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mAdapter = new MuaAdapter(muaView);

        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        // Item Click listener for CardView and Parcel CardView to new Intent

        mAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new MuaAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(int position) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MuaActivity.this, Customer1Activity.class);
                intent.putExtra("Customer's Details", muaView.get(position));
                startActivity(intent);
            }

        });

    }

    // Filter/Search Bar

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.search, menu);

        MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();

        searchView.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                mAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
                return false;
            }
        });
        return true;
    }
}
```

Here is my Adapter,

```
    package Adapters;

import android.com.example.weddingappfinale.MuaView;
import android.com.example.weddingappfinale.R;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Filter;
import android.widget.Filterable;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MuaAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MuaAdapter.MuaViewHolder> implements Filterable {

    private ArrayList<MuaView> mMuaView;
    private ArrayList<MuaView> mMuaViewFull;
    private OnItemClickListener mListener;

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(int position);
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
    }

    public static class MuaViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public ImageButton mImageButton;
        public TextView mTextView1;
        public TextView mDescription;

        public MuaViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView, final OnItemClickListener listener) {
            super(itemView);
            mImageButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.mua_imageButton);
            mTextView1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.mua_title);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (listener != null) {
                        int position = getAdapterPosition();
                        if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                            listener.onItemClick(position);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

            mImageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (listener != null) {
                        int position = getAdapterPosition();
                        if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                            listener.onItemClick(position);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public MuaAdapter(ArrayList<MuaView> muaView) {
       mMuaView = muaView;
       mMuaViewFull = new ArrayList<>(muaView);
    }

    @Override
    public MuaViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.mua_view, parent, false);
        MuaViewHolder mvh = new MuaViewHolder(v, mListener);
        return mvh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MuaViewHolder holder, int position) {
        MuaView currentView = mMuaView.get(position);

        holder.mImageButton.setImageResource(currentView.getImageResource());
        holder.mTextView1.setText(currentView.getText1());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mMuaView.size();
    }

    public Filter getFilter() {
        return MuaFilter;
    }

    private Filter MuaFilter = new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            List<MuaView> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();

            if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {
                filteredList.addAll(mMuaViewFull);
            } else {
                String filterPattern = constraint.toString().toLowerCase().trim();

                for (MuaView item : mMuaViewFull) {
                    if (item.getText1().toLowerCase().contains(filterPattern)) {
                        filteredList.add(item);
                    }
                }
            }

            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
            results.values = filteredList;

            return results;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            mMuaView.clear();
            mMuaView.addAll((ArrayList) results.values);
            notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    };
}
```

Here is my ModelView,

```
    package android.com.example.weddingappfinale;

import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

public class MuaView implements Parcelable {
    private int mImageResource;
    private String mText1;
    private String mDescription;
    private String mServices1;
    private String mServices2;
    private String mContact;
    private String mAddress;

    public MuaView(int imageResource, String text1, String description) {
        mImageResource = imageResource;
        mText1 = text1;
        mDescription = description;

    }

    protected MuaView(Parcel in) {
        mImageResource = in.readInt();
        mText1 = in.readString();
    }

    public static final Creator<MuaView> CREATOR = new Creator<MuaView>() {
        @Override
        public MuaView createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new MuaView(in);
        }

        @Override
        public MuaView[] newArray(int size) {
            return new MuaView[size];
        }
    };

    public MuaView(int mua_image, String shima_matin_bridal_services) {
    }

    public int getImageResource() {
        return mImageResource;
    }

    public String getText1() {
        return mText1;
    }

    public String getmDescription() {
        return mDescription;
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeInt(mImageResource);
        dest.writeString(mText1);
    }
}
```

Here is the template xml.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/image_customer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_margin="4dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title_customer"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/image_customer"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_margin="4dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/open_sans_semibold"
            android:text="" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/description"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Description:"
            android:layout_below="@id/title_customer"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:fontFamily="@font/open_sans_extrabold"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/descriptionVendor"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Description of Vendors"
            android:layout_below="@id/description"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/services"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/descriptionVendor"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/open_sans_extrabold"
            android:text="@string/services" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/services1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/services"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/services"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/services"
            android:text="Services1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/services2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/services1"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/services"
            android:text="Services2" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/gallery"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/services2"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/open_sans_extrabold"
            android:text="@string/gallery" />

        <com.denzcoskun.imageslider.ImageSlider
            android:id="@+id/imageslider"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/gallery"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_margin="4dp"
            app:delay="0"
            app:placeholder="@drawable/mua_image" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/contact"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/imageslider"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/open_sans_extrabold"
            android:text="Contact:"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/contactVendor"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/contact"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="ContactVendor" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/address"
            android:layout_below="@id/contactVendor"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Address:"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:fontFamily="@font/open_sans_extrabold"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/addressvendor"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/address"
            android:text="AddressVendor"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>


    </RelativeLayout>
</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Here is the activity of the template xml.

```
    package CustomerActivities;

import android.com.example.weddingappfinale.MuaView;
import android.com.example.weddingappfinale.R;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.denzcoskun.imageslider.ImageSlider;
import com.denzcoskun.imageslider.models.SlideModel;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Customer1Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_customer1_mua);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        MuaView muaView = intent.getParcelableExtra("Customer's Details");

        int imageRes = muaView.getImageResource();
        String line1 = muaView.getText1();
        String description = muaView.getmDescription();

        ImageButton imageButton = findViewById(R.id.image_customer);
        imageButton.setImageResource(imageRes);

        TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.descriptionVendor);
        textView.setText(description);

        TextView textView1 = findViewById(R.id.title_customer);
        textView1.setText(line1);

        ImageSlider imageSlider = findViewById(R.id.imageslider);
        List<SlideModel> slideModels = new ArrayList<>();
        slideModels.add(new SlideModel(R.drawable.catering_image));
        slideModels.add(new SlideModel(R.drawable.entertainment_image));
        imageSlider.setImageList(slideModels, true);


    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this:

```
public class MuaView implements Parcelable {
```

to this:

```
public class MuaView implements Serializable{
```

and change this

```
 MuaView muaView = intent.getParcelableExtra("Customer's Details");
```

to this:

```
 MuaView muaView = intent.getSerializableExtra("Customer's Details");
```